# rails rendering all actions via AJAX - is there an easy way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to make rails render actions via AJAX. I've read about respond_to and js.erb. But I really don't feel like going through every `link_to` and add `:remote => true`

But my main concern is **creating almost identical js.erb files**.

Is there a rails way of making an AJAXful website? Maybe something like inherited_resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The :remote => true bit on the link adds a data-remote attribute to the resulting HTML link.

Then there's the rails ujs driver that unobtrusively pick this up through the proper selector and adds the required headers to let Rails (ActionPack) understand that this is an AJAX request.

One solution might be to set, depending on the driver, all links to be AJAX (not sure if you want to do that) through Javascript or overriding/expanding/creating another helper method that has the :remote => true set.

Something around those lines:

```
def ajax_link_to(url, label)
    link_to label, url, :remote => true
end
```

Expand to include html options, etc, at will.

Or with alias_method_chain (untested):

```
def link_to_with_ajax(title, args = {})
  link_to_without_ajax(title, args.merge(:remote => true))
end
alias_method_chain :link_to, :ajax
```

Comment: Thanks. But again, this requires me to go through all my action links and change them.

Comment: I never saw a web application with 100% ajax links, however you can try to use alias_method_chain on link_to, I'll try to post an example.

Comment: I edited my reply to include alias_method_chain, not tested though, I'm in hospital :)

Answer (score 2):

I managed to convert all my links to AJAX through the use of jquery without the need to edit a single one.  I added the following to my $(document).ready

```
// Ajax navigation
$('a').live('click', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  link = $(this); 
  target = link.attr('target')
  $('#'+target).load(link.attr('href'), function() {});
});
```

I use it heavily in my shortcut jquery plugin https://github.com/map7/jquery.beeline

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default format type to JSON and then just call your controller actions as ajax. Here's a question that tells [how to set up the default format type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753862/how-do-i-set-the-default-format-like-json-for-a-customized-devise-controller-in). It seems you have to do this per resource. I've never tried this though...I only use ajax as needed rather than doing it with the entire site.

Comment: I guess, this should work with format.js. Thanks. But my biggest concern is rendering the html, since I'll have to make ~15-20 js.erb files, which is not very dry.

Comment: yep, that's not fun. you might poke around and see what other template gems there are and how each of those deal with this issue, if they do at all. However, I suspect there won't be an easy answer to this. Write a gem of your own and I'll use it!